# Update file metadata on SharePoint from Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm trying to update file metadata from Power Automate, using the REST api.

I need to format the Json code for the body and add the information which is to be updated.
I can't get this to work......

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The body would be like this:

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.ArchivedListItem"
  },
  "Title": "NewTitle"
}
```

Comment: I've been trying that, but I get the same error.

Input string was not in a correct format.

There's something wrong with the inputs but  can't find what.

Comment: @user16068355 - Just a thought - Are you using any special character in it ? or it would be great if you can show here in more details.

Comment: No special characters. I finally got it to work.....the column had been renamed a couple of times, and the reste API doesn't recognize the changes. I deleted the column and re-created it. I couldn't find a way to get the actual column name.

Comment: You should use the internal name of the column. Go to list settings, click the specific column. In the edit column page, you could find the internal name of the column in the end of the url.

Comment: Michael thanks. That ID is the same for all columns, and i think it's the lists GUID.

I am looking for a way to find the GUID's of columns in lists and libraries